# Gallery with two UIScrollViews not working properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I've an image gallery, that consists of `UIScrollView` that contains `UIScrollView` for each image.

So I can do zoom on each picture, but when I'm zoomed in, its not changing
to the next picture, until I return to the original size.

I've tried calling `resignNextResponder` in `scrollViewDidScroll` method when the `contentOffset` is out of bounds, but is doing nothing.

Any ideas?